# Functional equation $g(2x )= 1/2 g(x)$

Tags: functional-equations

I am trying to solve functional equation for $g: \ (0, \infty) \mapsto ( 0, \infty)$
$$ g( 2x ) =\frac 12 g(x)$$
Wolfram claims, and it is intuitive, that the function is $g(x) = C \frac{1}{x}$. But how to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Even assuming continuity, there are many more solutions:
Let $h\colon[1,2]\to(0,\infty)$ be any continuous function with $h(2)=\frac12h(1)$. Then 
$$ g(x)=2^{\lfloor\log_2 x\rfloor}h(2^{1+\lfloor \log_2 x\rfloor}/x)$$
is continuous and obeys your functional equation.
Similarly, we can find many arbitrarily smooth $g$.

Comment: The function should be continous and defined on the whole $(0 , \infty)$.

Comment: So **is** $g(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $g(x)$ has a [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) as $\;g(x)=C/x + \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n\;$ then by comparing coefficients show that $\;c_n=0\;$ for all $\;n\ge0\;$ because $\;g(2x)=C/(2x)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n 2^n x^n\;$ and $\;\frac12g(x)=C/(2x)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac12c_n  x^n\;$ implies $\;c_n2^n=\frac12c_n\;$ and $2^n\ne\frac12\;$ for all $\;n\ge0$.